# I want to pass a variable from file_field_tag to a rake task via the controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, rake

I want to pass the filename (`health_exported_zip`) to a controller action then on to a rake task. The rake task imports selected data from `export.zip` into the database and the rake task works if I hard code `health_exported_zip` into the rake task. But I can't get the variable from the page to the controller, nor from the controller to the rake task.

`index.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag( action: :import_data, controller: :some_models ) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :health_exported_zip %>
  <%= submit_tag( "Import" ) %>
<% end %>
```

`some_models_controller.rb`

```
def import_data
  health_exported_zip = @health_exported_zip
  puts "health_exported_zip: #{health_exported_zip}. Selected"
  @health_exported_zip = "/Users/gscar/Downloads/export.zip"
  puts "@health_exported_zip: #{@health_exported_zip}. Hard coded in controller"
  system "rails import:some_models[#{@health_exported_zip}]"
  ...
end
```

`lib/tasks/import.rake`

```
...
extract_zip(health_exported_zip, unzip_to_dir) # line 49
...
```

Console:

```
Started POST "/import_data" for ::1 at 2021-11-11 21:24:24 -0800
Processing by SomeModelsController#import_data as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Import"}
health_exported_zip: . Selected
@health_exported_zip: /Users/gscar/Downloads/export.zip. Hard coded in controller
rails aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `health_exported_zip' for main:Object
~/lib/tasks/import.rake:49:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for any pointers.

PS. One old Rails 3 suggestion

> rake tasks are not intended to be run from a controller. Consider
> refactoring and extracting take task functionality to separate method.
> Then you can call this method both from the rake task and the
> controller action.

Assume this still holds and I can do that when I get it working.

Comment: That suggestion is ok. If I were to write an answer I'd say the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. But i still need to get the value to the controller

Comment: You should try `params[: health_exported_zip]` instead of `health_exported_zip`

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `<input type="file" name="health_exported_zip">` does not appear in the params that come to the controller:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Import"}
```

It may be related to you trying to upload a file thru web sockets (turbo stream):

```
SomeModelsController#import_data as TURBO_STREAM
```

First try to use a form with normal HTTP POST request, and have the input name appear among the `params` keys in the log. When it is there, it will have a long local file path to a temp directory at your machine.

Then address that local file path as `params[:health_exported_zip]`.